# Shiny tableOutput: 'Error: could not find function "df"'

Tags: r, shiny, dt

When I try to code a tableOutput or DTOutput into my Shiny app I get the 'Error: could not find function "daysSince10"'.

I've tried validate(need()) and also require(). Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

daysSince10 <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joegoodman94/CoronavirusTracker/master/days10.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Coronavirus Tracker"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(selectInput('Country', 'Select Country', multiple = T, unique(daysSince10$`Country`))),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot", plotly::plotlyOutput('trend')),
        tabPanel("Table", DT::DTOutput('table'))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    moddays <- daysSince10[daysSince10$`Country` %in% input$Country,]
    output$trend <- plotly::renderPlotly({
      validate(
        need(input$Country, "please select a country")
      ) 
      ggplot(moddays) +
        geom_line(aes(x = `Days since tenth death`, y = `Total Deaths`, color = `Country`)) +
        scale_y_log10()
    })
    output$table <- DT::renderDT({
      validate(
        need(input$Country, "please select a country")
      )      
      daysSince10()
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`output$XXX <- renderYYY()` assignments should generally live outside of an `observe()`.

Was `output$table` meant to depend on `moddays` rather than `daysSince10`? Assuming this is the case:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  moddays <- reactive({
    daysSince10[daysSince10$`Country` %in% input$Country,]
  })

  output$trend <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    validate(
      need(input$Country, "please select a country")
    ) 
    ggplot(moddays()) +
      geom_line(aes(x = `Days since tenth death`, y = `Total Deaths`, color = `Country`)) +
      scale_y_log10()
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
    validate(
      need(input$Country, "please select a country")
    )      
    moddays()
  })
}
```

Making `moddays` a reactive of its own, that should now be referred to in subsequent code as `moddays()` (a function call)

Answer (score 0):

Don't write `daysSince10()`, but `daysSince10` without parentheses.
Because of them, R looks for a function named "daysSince10", which does not exist.

```r
output$table <- DT::renderDT({
  validate(
    need(input$Country, "please select a country")
  )      
  daysSince10
})
```